# Query plan or execution plan specifies cost in percentagewise. What is the percentagewise according to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

What is the cost, percentage-wise, in query plan execution?

```
SELECT a.au_fname + ''+ a.au_lname AS 'Author Name',
t.title
FROM authors a INNER JOIN titleauthor ta
ON (a.au_id = ta.au_id) INNER JOIN titles t
ON (ta.title_id = t.title_id)

select * from authors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server:

Cost percentage is the relative percentage to the whole batch of queries executing. If you are executing a single query, the percentage for that would be always 100%.

> Each query in the batch that is
>   analyzed is displayed, **including the
>   cost of each query as a percentage of
>   the total cost of the batch**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx

Comment: @sly_Chandan: Did you run both of them in the same batch?

Comment: But I see only one query in the question. So you ran this and another query at the same time?

Comment: Yes. What do u mean by batch. Which batch are u talking about?

Comment: By batch I mean, are you pasting both the queries in the same editor window and executing using a single keystroke of 'F5' in Management studio!

Comment: first query takes 83% and second query takes 13%...my question is what is the percentage measured as? cpu time to execute the query or something else

Comment: Yup it is the time to execute.